# Compilación en Java

Tags: java

tengo una duda al momento de compilar en java, ¿todas la variables o métodos empiezan a crearse y almacenarse en la memoria al momento de compilar?.

```
public Class MiClase{

     private int x; //Cuando se compila, ¿todo lo que esta en la clase, ya sea 
                    //métodos o variables, se llega a crear y almacenarse en 
                    //la memoria RAM?

     private int y;

     public int metodo1(){
      .....
     }

     public int metodo2(){
      .....
     }
}
```

Si la respuesta es SI, tengo una segunda duda, las variables que ocupan memoria deben tener una dirección de memoria así como los objetos. Mi pregunta es, ¿Cuándo se instancia un objeto de tipo MiClase(Es el nombre de la clase del ejemplo anterior), al momento de que el objeto de use las variables, esas dichas variables ya NO estarán en su dirección de memoria anterior(osea, ya NO estarán en su dirección de memoria donde fueron colocadas por la memoria RAM), ahora su dirección actual sería la dirección del objeto, ya que estas están almacenadas dentro de la memoria del objeto? ¿Verdad, o estoy mal? Quisiera que me ayuden a disipar estas dudas, ya que son solo preguntas teóricas, y todos sabemos que saber programación, hay que tener una buena base de teoría.

Answer (score 4):

Hay un error fundamental en tu planteamiento y es asumir que la compilación hace algún tipo de reserva en memoria principal para los datos. Ten muy en cuenta que la compilación no es más que la traducción de un programa lenguaje de alto nivel a otro generalmente de más bajo nivel, pero el resultado no deja de ser eso: un programa, una lista de pasos a seguir, la implementación de un algoritmo si prefieres. Esta etapa se realiza mediante el comando `javac` o mediante el botón de compilar en tu entorno de desarrollo de preferencia y no involucra aún el uso del comando `java` o el botón de ejecutar.

Nota: Si tu IDE solo tiene botón de "compilar y ejecutar", te recomiendo dejarte un momento de mimos y probar usar los comandos mencionados a mano limpia (dentro de tu terminal). Puede que necesites añadir la ubicación de los binarios a la variable de entorno PATH para poder ejecutar directamente los comandos, aquí te dejo un video de cómo hacerlo:[Variable de entorno PATH](https://www.youtube.cAom/watch?v=CoXWrCyyV3Y)).

Volviendo a lo importante, solo hasta que llames al intérprete de java para iniciar la ejecución del programa será que los pasos de tu algoritmo serán realmente cargados en la RAM, sin embargo, eso no significa que todas las clases y elementos del programa sean cargados a la par.

Al ejecutar el programa se especifica una única clase con método `main` para iniciar la ejecución, la cual será la única que será cargada en memoria en un principio. En poco tiempo se le unirán las otras clases a las que se haga referencia en el código a ejecutar, las cuales se determinaron en la etapa de resolución de enlaces o enlazado (Uno de los pasos de la compilación).

Hasta este punto, sin embargo, solo se ha reservado memoria para los datos e instrucciones cargadas y para los atributos estáticos de las mismas (aunque dichos atributos estáticos siguen sin estar inicializados), por lo que aún no hay memoria para los atributos de instancia. Con apenas demora empieza la etapa de inicialización en que se ejecutan las inicializaciones (valga la redundancia) de los atributos estáticos, los bloques de código de inicialización de clase o se le da a cada atributo de clase su valor por defecto si este no ha sido inicializado explícitamente. Hasta este punto se puede responder una fracción de tu pregunta:
¿Cuándo yo creo un objeto estoy usando memoria previamente reservada? R: La única memoria que se reserva de antemano es la de los atributos estáticos, al carecer tu código de los mismos entonces no. En caso de que tuvieras un atributo estático inicializado con el constructor de la clase y posteriormente lo reasignaras, la respuesta seguiría siendo no también porque cada llamada al constructor te regresa un objeto en una dirección no asignada previamente.

Finalmente llegamos la última actividad en la agenda de inicialización de la JVM: comenzar la ejecución en la función main. Es en este punto donde potencialmente se crean variables de la clase en cuestión y se les asigna instancias nuevas mediante el constructor. Es en este momento en que los miembros de instancia como “x” e “y” son creados a la par del número de llamadas al constructor que haga tu programa. En ningún momento previo había reservado un lugar en memoria para ellos y ahora que si lo hay este espacio será independiente por cada objeto creado.

Te dejo un enlace hacia la explicación de las etapas de inicio de la máquina virtual de java:

[Java Virtual Machine Startup](http://techieme.in/activities-following-the-java-virtual-machine-startup/)

Comment: Estoy muy agradecido por tu respuesta mi estimado "Saul Axel Martinez Ortiz", un aporte a mi parecer muy completo, aunque hay partes en la que sinceramente no llegue a entender, PERO puse en práctica el resto y lo que no entendí lo llegue a buscar aparte y también ha estar experimentado con los comandos javac y java. Si no fuera mucha molestia, le pediría amablemente que me comparta un libro de donde saco esta información y también que llegase hacer un vídeo explicando todo esto, ya que no hay tutoriales que expliquen como usted me explico a mí. Posdata,gracias también por el link de la página

Comment: Buena respuesta, aunque creo que con una división en párrafos iría mejor.

Comment: La verdad, es uno de los temas que deberían estar en primera pagina en las preguntas de java. Esta respuesta es bastante acertada, aunque hecho de menos un poco de separacion o imágenes, pero eso ya es ir a por la matrícula de honor